# Get value from tool tip html element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an image that shows users some text field (username and password) as tool tip when over around.

```
<div class="user-pos">
    <ul id ="users" class="user-list">
        <li id="def-html" data-tooltip="#html-content"><img src="img/new.png" /></li>
    </ul>
    <div id = "html-content" style="display:none;">

        <p class="newuser">Create a new user account</p>
        <br/>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <label for="createUsername">Choose a username</label>
            <input type="text"  id="createUsername" required autocomplete="name">
            <label for="createPassword">Enter your password</label>
            <input type="password"  id="createPassword" required value="gdh" autocomplete="name">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <label for="createEmail">Enter your email</label>
            <input type="text"  id="createEmail" required>
            <label for="createPasswordVerify">Confirm password</label>
            <input type="password"  id="createPasswordVerify"  required >
        </div>
        <div class="userbut"><button onclick="createAccount()"class="btn btn-sm btn-info">Create Account</button></div>

    </div>
</div>
```

This javascript function is meant to get values from those fields and use it.

```
function createAccount() {
    var password = $('#createPassword').val();
    var veriPas = $('#createPasswordVerify').val();
    var username = $('#createUsername').val();
    var email = $('#createEmail').val();
    if (email.trim() === "") {
        alert('email  is empty');
    } else if (password.trim() === "") {
        alert('password  is empty');
    } else if (password != veriPas) {
        alert('Password did not match');
    } else {
        var isReg = app.regUser(email, password, 1, false);
        if (isReg) {
            alert('user created');
        } else {
            alert('no user creation');
        }
    }
}
```

Problem is the fields are always empty. The js code works when div "html-content" is not used as a tooltip but fails if it is shown as tool tip when user overs around the image. How do i Fix this

Comment: Where is the code that fires the hover event ?

Comment: data-tooltip="#html-content" attribute on <li> made this possible

Comment: I can't even get the hover to fire in js fiddle.  any idea why ?

Answer (score 1):

In your html, the password input box has an ID of "frmNameA"
but in your JavaScript function you reference it with

```
var password = $('#createPassword').val();
```

Check that the IDs for the inputs are the same as the ones your function is using.

Answer (score 1):

### Update

This might work...

```
$('#def-html').tooltip({
    content: $("#html-content").html()       
})
```

---

Try this,  I'm not sure how the data-tooltip scope is set up, but this may help.

Or try `$('body input#createPassword').val();`

Also, you can put the div in its own file and use CSS content to call it with url combined with one of the methods for selecting that I've provided here.

```
#html-content:hover:after {
    content: " (" url('myfilewithdivinit.html') ")";
}
```

Example using .find(), this may work also....  more of a chance if you combine it with the CSS content method above.

```
function createAccount() {
    var password = $('body').find('input#createPassword').val();
    var veriPas = $('body').find('input#createPasswordVerify').val();
    var username = $('body').find('input#createUsername').val();
    var email = $('body').find('input#createEmail').val();
    if (email.trim() === "") {
        alert('email  is empty');
    } else if (password.trim() === "") {
        alert('password  is empty');
    } else if (password != veriPas) {
        alert('Password did not match');
    } else {
        var isReg = app.regUser(email, password, 1, false);
        if (isReg) {
            alert('user created');
        } else {
            alert('no user creation');
        }
    }
}
```

Also, you should add a type attribute to your button.

```
<button type="button" onclick="createAccount()"class="btn btn-sm btn-info">Create Account</button>
```